# Google Wave Python Tutorial - What next?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-wave

I just finished working through Google's [Wave Robot: Python Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/robots/python-tutorial.html). The [API Reference](http://wave-robot-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/index.html) looks a bit imposing. Is there anything else I can look at to get up to speed?

Comment: The API indeed is imposing. You can only respond to *wave* events because those are calling your /_wave/* web service. With external events (e.g. if you want to run a timer to poll some website), you cannot call into the wave API to change something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the Python sample bots on the sample gallery : http://wave-samples-gallery.appspot.com/results?language=Python&api=Robots. This can give you ideas of bots to make, and show you good practices, too. The gallery outlines the specific features of the API used by each bot.

Also, you could join the Wave API group on http://groups.google.com/group/google-wave-api. There's pretty good talk on there about it.

Answer (score 1):

Building the robot is fairly straight forward conceptually. The Python API itself however is buggy and hard to work with.

Were you able to build a simple robot that responds to commands? That's a start IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to try to implement some small program and start experimenting with some features starting from the one that are kind of simple. In this way you build momentum and will adventure in the deepest part of it. Of course reading the code of the api itself will help A LOT, and is python so ... a pleasant lecture.